# run commands in openssl from ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh, openssl, exec

I'm trying to run the following commands over ssh in ruby.

```
[root@test]# /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
OpenSSL> version
1.0.2d
OpenSSL> exit
```

Here's my code :

```
def execute(cmd)
   puts cmd
   result = con.exec!(cmd)
   result = result.strip! unless result==nil
   p "command output execute() :: #{result}"
   return result
 end

con.execute("/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl && version && exit")
```

The first command leads to OpenSSL prompt. How do I run commands in it?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Open3.html ? You need to write to the stdin of the process... Note that after a command you do need to read all the output. That means knowing when the next prompt is given, or you'll block.

Comment: Note that it is much easier to directly call the openssl command line `openssl version` or - even better - to program against an OpenSSL wrapper API.

Comment: I tried con.execute("/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl version") and it worked! Thank you! :)